Does a finite-dimensional $basic$ algebra have the same length as a regular module when considered as a left module and as a right module?
Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional basic algebra over a field $k$. A  finite-dimensional algebra $A$ is called a basic algebra if $A$ has the property that if
$$A = \bigoplus^{n}_{i=1}P_{i}$$
with the $P_{i}$ indecomposable projective modules, then $P_{i} \not\cong P_{j}$ for $i \neq j$.
Naturally, $A$ can be considered as a left $A-module$ and as a right $A-module$. So the question arises:
Does a finite-dimensional basic algebra $A$ have the same length as a regular module when considered as a left module and as a right module? In other words, do we always have
$$l(_{A}A)  =  l(A_{A})\ \ ,$$
where $l(_{A}A)$ and $l(A_{A})$ denote the length of $A$ as a left module and as a right module, respectively?
If $A$ is not a basic finite-dimensional algebra, there is a counterexample.

The example I left in the comment to the solution you linked is a basic algebra:
$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb C & \mathbb H \\ 0 & \mathbb H\end{bmatrix}$
(You can tell it's basic since $R/J(R)$ is a finite product of division rings, as opposed to the other example, where it contains a nontrivial matrix ring.)
IIRC it has left composition length 4 and right composition length 3.

This is an awesome counterexample for the above question. You are so intelligent, thank you so much for your patience in providing the counterexample once more.
